# How to project only some part of your computer screen

Tags: windows-10, display

I am an instructor. I do live development demos to students.

Recently I bought a 17.3 inch laptop that supports high resolutions.

Projector resolution is low, so forexample 1/4 of this screen space is enough for stuff that I want to show to students.

I want to be able to use the rest of the screen for other purposes, e.g. for notes that only I want to see. These notes should be invisible to students.

How can I achieve this? Free/cheap software is welcome. I have Windows 10 installed.

Comment: Press Win+P and instead of using duplicate use extend. You could also use some form of screen recording software like OBS and it's preview pane to display only a part. There is probably some specialized software for this as well but I'm not sure what you would look for.

Comment: The projector screen is behind me. Using extend is not a good solution in this case. Thanks anyways.

Comment: If you share power point presentations,  then use presenter view to follow presentation on you're laptop's screen.

Comment: I know that. But i need a more general solution. E.g. I will develop a program live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## VLC Rocks

Open your desktop as a capture device in VLC

`Media > Open Capture Device... > Capture Mode: Desktop > Play`

Crop the screen using

`Tools > Effects and Filters > Video Effects > Crop`

Move the VLC window onto the screen being projected, then press `F` to make it fullscreen.

[image: screenshot of vlc capturing screen with video effects window open]

---

### Scripting

Once you know what crop values you want, if you want a quick double-click solution, you should be able to make a file named `vlc-presentation.bat` and copy and paste this into it:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --fullscreen --qt-fullscreen-screennumber=0 --no-qt-fs-controller --video-filter=croppadd --croppadd-croptop=100 --croppadd-cropbottom=100 --croppadd-cropleft=250 --croppadd-cropright=250 screen://`

It's a lot to take in, so here's some explanation from VLC's help output:

> ```
> -f, --fullscreen, --no-fullscreen
>                              Fullscreen video output (default disabled)
>       Start video in fullscreen mode (default disabled)
>
> --qt-fullscreen-screennumber=<integer [-2147483648 .. 2147483647]>
>                              Define which screen fullscreen goes
>       Screennumber of fullscreen, instead of same screen where interface is
>
> --qt-fs-controller, --no-qt-fs-controller
>                              Show a controller in fullscreen mode (default
>                              enabled)
>       Show a controller in fullscreen mode (default enabled)
>
> --video-filter=<string>    Video filter module
>       This adds post-processing filters to enhance the picture quality, for
>       instance deinterlacing, or distort the video.
>
>  Video scaling filter    Crop:
>   --croppadd-croptop=<integer [0 .. 2147483647]>
>                              Pixels to crop from top
>       Number of pixels to crop from the top of the image.
>
>   --croppadd-cropbottom=<integer [0 .. 2147483647]>
>                              Pixels to crop from bottom
>       Number of pixels to crop from the bottom of the image.
>
>   --croppadd-cropleft=<integer [0 .. 2147483647]>
>                              Pixels to crop from left
>       Number of pixels to crop from the left of the image.
>
>   --croppadd-cropright=<integer [0 .. 2147483647]>
>                              Pixels to crop from right
>       Number of pixels to crop from the right of the image.
> ```

You will need to tweak the command according to where VLC is installed on your computer, which screen you want the fullscreen vlc window to appear on, and how much you want it to be cropped.

I'm not sure if you can tell vlc which screen it should capture.

---

### Mouse Cursor

Due to *reasons*, VLC can't directly record the mouse cursor on your desktop.

However, you can add the `--screen-mouse-image` argument to tell VLC to use a small icon instead of your mouse cursor:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --fullscreen --qt-fullscreen-screennumber=0 --no-qt-fs-controller --screen-mouse-image=C:\Users\msbob\Pictures\mouse-cursor.png --video-filter=croppadd --croppadd-croptop=100 --croppadd-cropbottom=100 --croppadd-cropleft=250 --croppadd-cropright=250 screen://`

Comment: yeah it does. So follow up question: is there a way to prevent so much click

Comment: Yeah VLC actually does rock! Now a follow up question: is there a way to prevent so many clicks, e.g. write a script to automatize this setup? (System did not allow me to edit my earlier post, which was posted without finishing its writing).

Comment: @meteora I've added a script to automate this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I changed screennumber to 1 and it directly goes to the right screen. Cool!. Two questions now: 1-) Mouse pointer is not seen in the capture. How can that be fixed? 2-) How can I arrange the "Desired frame rate for the capture". I tried to put `--screen-fps=10.000000` to bat file. But it does not work.

Comment: @meteora The [documentation](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/screen/) for the screen module says you need to use an Integer.  e.g.  `--screen-fps=10`.  Just remove the decimal point and all those zeroes.

Comment: @meteora Sorry, I just realized I didn't answer your question about the mouse.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply but for people who are still looking for something like this.

1. In PowerPoint you can work in PowerPoint and set the presentation on your 2nd screen while working on it. In that case you can work on the PPT canvas and people only see the canvas.
2. OBS studio, there is a YouTube  [tutorial](https://youtu.be/42UTUCohh5A)